# Error linking wasm object files with wasm-ld

Tags: llvm, webassembly

I'm trying to link two simple wasm files with wasm-ld (the llvm wasm linker)

The wasm files are compiled from 2 simple wat files (mod_a.wat and mod_b.wat - see code below) with wabt tools. More precisely:

```
;;mod_a.wat
(module $mod_a
  (import "mod_b" "square" (func $square (param i32) (result i32)))

  (start $start)

  ;; _start entry point expected by wasm-ld
  (func $start
    (drop (call $square (i32.const 16)))
  )
)

;;mod_b.wat
(module $mod_b
  (export "square" (func $square))

  (func $square (param $value i32) (result i32)
    (i32.mul (local.get $value) (local.get $value))
  )
)


$ wat2wasm -r ./mod_a.wat
$ wat2wasm -r ./mod_b.wat
$ wasm-ld-8 ./mod_a.wasm ./mod_b.wasm -o main.wasm
wasm-ld-8: error: entry symbol not defined (pass --no-entry to supress): _start
wasm-ld-8: error: ./mod_a.wasm: undefined symbol: square
```

I don't quite understand why those 2 symbols are undefined (note: whether I name the start function $start or $_start doesn't change a thing). And it certainly dosn't explain why the square function is not recognized.

Any idea ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, are  `(start $start)` and `(export "_start" (func $start))` actually the same? Also, the situation seems to have improved from llvm 8 to 11. I can now make your example work by renaming `$start` to `$_start` (Those names shouldn't matter, I thought. Instead, it doesn't seem to matter whether `(start $_start)` is declared).

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` flag to wat2wasm only supports the bare minimum of the wasm object file format.   It doesn't support writing out a symbol table for example, which admittedly makes it fairly useless.   Your best option for producing a linkable object file today is to use llvm (either using clang or handwritten assembly in .s format).

Comment: I filed a bug to remove this flag completely to avoid confusion going forward: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/issues/1137